# hdiutil: Creating case-sensitive image fs for Steam

Tags: macos, filesystem, steam

I'm attempting to use Steam on my Mac, but I set up my system to have case-sensitivity.

[Steam has a thread for setting up an image file with a case-sensitive file system](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1268621), however, I'm finding that it doesn't work.

Regardless of whether I create the sparse image from Disk Utility or from `hdiutil`, I get a mount-error.

```
hdiutil: attach failed - no mountable file systems
```

However, as far as I can tell I've created the file correctly?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

MOUNTPT="/.000"
SPARSEIMG="/Users/Shared/Steam/steam.sparseimage"

if [ ! -e "${MOUNTPT}" ]; then
    echo "sudo mkdir -m0777 ${MOUNTPT}"
    sudo mkdir -m0777 "${MOUNTPT}"
fi

if [ ! -e "${SPARSEIMG}" ]; then
    hdiutil create -type SPARSE -fs 'Case-sensitive Journaled HFS+' -size 32g "${SPARSEIMG}"
fi

hdiutil attach -mountpoint "${MOUNTPT}" -nobrowse "${SPARSEIMG}"
```

Can anyone tell me what I am not doing correctly?

UPDATE:
The image that's created mounts properly in Disk Utility, but does not with `hdiutil`

Comment: The link to the Steam article just goes to the main forum page so it is impossible to see what the thread says - making the question not understandable

Comment: @Mark - the link is irrelevant to diagnose the error specified in the question.  Additionally, this question has an answer that addresses it.

Answer (score 1):

It's a better practice to leave all uppercase variables for the shell and use lower and or mixed case for user variables in scripts. You need to preface the `hdiutil attach ...` *command* too with `sudo` if using `/.000` as the mount point.

Here's my version of the *script* which works.

---

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

mountpt="/.000"
sparseimg="/Users/Shared/Steam/steam.sparseimage"

[ ! -d "$mountpt" ] &&  sudo mkdir -m0777 "$mountpt"
[ ! -e "$sparseimg" ] && hdiutil create -type SPARSE -fs 'Case-sensitive Journaled HFS+' -size 32g "$sparseimg"

sudo hdiutil attach -mountpoint "$mountpt" -nobrowse "$sparseimg"
```

---

[image]

Comment: If you read the reference page from Steam, it requires its whole path to be case sensitive hence the very gross `/.000`. I'm going to include the link for your reference: http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1268621

Comment: @BCqrstoO, Okay then my updated answer will work.